# How to filter the edit comments admin page, show only current logged in author comments

Tags: comments, admin, author

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Filtering the Admin Comments List to Show Only Comments from the Current User?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/56652/filtering-the-admin-comments-list-to-show-only-comments-from-the-current-user)

I am trying to get the edit-comments admin page to only show comments for the logged in author. Comments left on their posts that is. It shows all comments but disables the logged in author from viewing/editing ones that are not his/hers.

How can I get only the comments from his/her posts to show up? I looked through the edit-comments.php file but couldn't find anywhere to hook into or filter.

Thanx in advance!