# Hide notifications regarding new comments

Tags: comments, author

[This is a follow-up on this question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/235987/hiding-comments-from-other-authors).

I have now added the code from [this page](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/56652/filtering-the-admin-comments-list-to-show-only-comments-from-the-current-user) and it helped hiding comments pertaining to the other authors.

Now I only need to have the notification removed, as it shows up for other authors than the ones to whom the comment is addressed: 
[image]
[image]

Is that even possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based off of the code from [another question that you referenced](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/56657/98212), I've added onto it by changing the total number of comment using `jQuery`:

```
add_filter( 'the_comments', 'wpse_236055_filter_comments' );
add_action( 'admin_head', 'wpse_236055_comment_notification' );

function wpse_236055_filter_comments( $comments ){ // Display comments related to the author
    global $pagenow, $user_ID, $comment_count;

    wp_get_current_user();
    if ( $pagenow == 'edit-comments.php' && current_user_can( 'author' ) ) {
        foreach( $comments as $i => $comment ) {
            $the_post = get_post( $comment -> comment_post_ID );
            if ( $comment -> user_id != $user_ID  && $the_post -> post_author != $user_ID ) {
                unset( $comments[$i] );
            }
        }
    }
    $comment_count = count( $comments );
    // echo '<!-- DEBUG PRINT --> <pre>'; print_r( $comment_count ); echo '</pre>';
    return $comments;
}

function wpse_236055_comment_notification( $comments ) { // Only show total count of comment related to the author
    global $pagenow, $comment_count;
    $site_name = 'Comments (' . count( $comments ) . ') ‹ ' . get_bloginfo( 'name' ) .  ' — WordPress';

    if ( !current_user_can( 'administrator' ) ) {
        ?>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            jQuery( document ).ready( function( $ ) {
                $( '.pending-count' ).html( '<?php echo $comment_count; ?>' );
                $( '.comment-count-pending' ).html( '<?php echo $comment_count; ?>' );
            } );
        </script>
        <?php
        }
    if ( $pagenow == 'edit-comments.php' && !current_user_can( 'administrator' ) ) {
        ?>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            jQuery( document ).ready( function( $ ) {
                $( document.title = '<?php echo $site_name; ?>' );
            } );
        </script>
        <?php
    }
}
```

As a result, the *Comments* menu item will only show the number of comments related to the author instead of the total number of comments. This has been tested on my end and it works.

Comment: Thanks - but won't it hide the notification for the author to whom the comment is directed also?

Comment: That's correct. This function hides the notification for everyone. May you provide me an example on how a comment is directed to an author? This way I can determine the best way to approach it.

Comment: I have a multi user blog with several authors on it. They each write blog posts under a unique name - for instance, Melissa and Camilla.

I have found out how to hide Melissas blog posts from Camilla and vice versa in the backend. Also, Melissa can't see the comments directed to Camillas blog posts. But there is still a red notification marker, when a new blog post has been added to Camillas post - and Melissa can see it when she logs into her account. When she clicks it, there are no comments to show, because the comment is directed at Camillas blog post and therefore hidden for Melissa.

Comment: I see. Hm... very interesting request. What have you tried on your end?

Comment: @Aztrid, updated my code it's been tested and it works. Please give me your feedback.

Comment: Thanks! quick question:

Should I remove this:

    add_filter('the_comments', 'wpse56652_filter_comments');

    function wpse56652_filter_comments($comments){
    global $pagenow;
    global $user_ID;
    get_currentuserinfo();
    if($pagenow == 'edit-comments.php' && current_user_can('author')){
        foreach($comments as $i => $comment){
            $the_post = get_post($comment->comment_post_ID);
            if($comment->user_id != $user_ID  && $the_post->post_author !=     $user_ID)
                unset($comments[$i]);
        }
    }
    return $comments;
    }

Comment: @Aztrid yes, replace that with my function. I've included it as part of the answer.

Comment: it works :-D and also, which is very good, the comment notification is not hidden for admins. Nice job ^_^

Comment: Great. Be sure to upvote this answer and click the green checkmark to indicate that this question is solved.

Comment: I tried to upvote, but I don't think my rep is big enough. Checked the checkmark, though :-)

Comment: Appreciate it. I enjoyed working on this question